# [Postgres][SQL]Window functions (count/average) where partitioning by weeks

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to run a window function where the partition is for a date column and I need the the values to be aggregated in a weekly interval.

For example in this dataset

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | 10 |
| 02-01-2022 | 15 |
| 10-01-2022 | 01 |
| 11-01-2022 | 12 |
| 20-01-2022 | 09 |
| 25-01-2022 | 08 |

I want a window function to calculate the average of the value column for the first week (starting 01-01-2022) of 2022, and the subsequent weeks.

Currently creating a new column with the week number for each entry and partitioning on that new column is the only way I can think of solving this. Is there a more elegant way that I'm not familiar with within the window functions in Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PG14+ [date_bin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) function is a good option. A pre-PG14 date_bin implementation [here](https://github.com/stefanov-sm/Pre-PG14-date_bin-function).

```sql
select date_bin('1 week', "Date", '2022-01-01') as "Week", 
       avg("Value") as "Avg"
from the_table 
group by "Week";
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT  date
    ,   value
    ,   TO_CHAR(date, 'WW')::INT AS weeknumber
    ,   AVG(value) OVER(PARTITION BY TO_CHAR(date, 'WW')::INT)
FROM    table_name
ORDER BY date;
```

Usually I don't use WW, but IW the ISO week numbering. But that's up to you.